# SQL, issue with case when comparing varchars

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Firstly my code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION exchangeRate(from_in VARCHAR2(5), to_in VARCHAR2(5)) RETURN NUMBER IS 
  exchange_rate NUMBER;
BEGIN
    CASE
        WHEN to = 'USD' THEN 
        CASE
            WHEN from = 'EUR' THEN exchange_rate := 25.49;
            ELSE exchange_rate := 1;
        END CASE;
        ELSE exchange_rate := 1;
    END CASE;
  RETURN exchange_rate;
END;
```

This is shorter version, i removed the adittional whens as they are identical (only different in currency and rates). However i do not understand the reason for this, i would ask for help with understanding the error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION exchangeRate(from_in table.currency%TYPE, to_in table.currency%TYPE) RETURN table.price%TYPE IS 
  exchange_rate table.price%TYPE;
BEGIN
    CASE
        WHEN to = 'USD' THEN 
        CASE
            WHEN from = 'EUR' THEN exchange_rate := 25.49;
            ELSE exchange_rate := 1;
        END CASE;
        ELSE exchange_rate := 1;
    END CASE;
  RETURN exchange_rate;
END;
```

And as i am not sure what is wrong with that, i would also like to ask whether i can use `table.row%TYPE` to declare parameter and return type

Edit: i only renamed it to "from" and "to" in here, i apologise for that, the original code had different names (which were bit too random)

Comment: We will try to help, but we need to know the error first.

Comment: How does one find a specific error that occured?

Comment: Neither of your posted code samples will compile. If you want us to help you must post the actual code you're running, or at least code which demonstrates the problem you have. As it is you've told us you have an error, without saying **what that error is**. If the error is actually a compilation error then you need to say so, and post the the error.

Comment: "How does one find a specific error that occured?" Your question says you have an error. Something must have happened when you tried to run the code. Just telling us what that is would be useful. But most Oracle environments are good at displaying the whole error stack. It's not good that you'e not sure what the specific error is. What client are you using to write and run the code?

Comment: "warning: function created with compilation errors" and i am using gqlplus. But as the answers below suggested, my mistake was in specifying size of VARCHAR2.

Comment: `show errors` immediately following compilation will show errors for that item. (People often add that to the end of the source code script.) The full syntax is `show errors [object type] [object name]` e.g. `show errors function exchangerate`. Or use proper desktop dev tools that give you this kind of information and more automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `from` as a parameter name, because it is keyword.

It is recommended to use some prefix when declaring parameter, so in your example, instead of `from` and `to` parameters, use `p_from` and `p_to`.

Moreover, remove size declaration of varchars in function parameters.
Your procedure will compile if will looks like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION exchangeRate(p_from VARCHAR2, p_to VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER IS 
  exchange_rate NUMBER;
BEGIN
    CASE
        WHEN p_to = 'USD' THEN 
        CASE
            WHEN p_from = 'EUR' THEN exchange_rate := 25.49;
            ELSE exchange_rate := 1;
        END CASE;
        ELSE exchange_rate := 1;
    END CASE;
  RETURN exchange_rate;
END;
```

According to your second question: Yes, you can use table types for both parameters and return types.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have previously tried the %TYPE but i must have had another error which convinced me it was wrong. The "from" wasn't an issue as i renamed the variables for stackoverflow because the original ones were random and i did not realise i what i wrote. But the error was in me specifying size of varchar2.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**:

Other answers have already explained what's wrong with your code.

Here's how you could simplify  your `CASE` statement.

```
CREATE OR replace FUNCTION Exchangerate(p_from VARCHAR2, 
                                        p_to   VARCHAR2) 
RETURN NUMBER 
IS 
  exchange_rate NUMBER; 
BEGIN 
    exchange_rate := CASE p_to 
                       WHEN 'USD' THEN CASE p_from 
                                         WHEN 'EUR' THEN 25.49 
                                         ELSE 1 
                                       END 
                       ELSE 1 
                     END; 

    RETURN exchange_rate; 
END;
```

Or this return statement should be equivalent

```
RETURN CASE 
           WHEN p_to = 'USD' 
              AND p_from = 'EUR' THEN 25.49 
           ELSE 1 
END;
```

and get rid of `exchange_rate` variable

Answer (score 2):

There is issue with your code is that you can't use varchar(size) as input parameter simply use data type without specifying size.

And from is keyword so you can't use it as input parameter.

Below code working fine, you can try it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION exchangeRate(from_in VARCHAR2, to_in VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER IS 
  exchange_rate NUMBER;
BEGIN
    CASE
        WHEN to_in = 'USD' THEN 
        CASE
            WHEN from_in = 'EUR' THEN exchange_rate := 25.49;
            ELSE exchange_rate := 1;
        END CASE;
        ELSE exchange_rate := 1;
    END CASE;
  RETURN exchange_rate;
END;
```